# Hashcat, finding out the Hash

Tags: encryption, password-cracking

I've been searching but I can't seem to find the much information on how to extract hash's from say PDF files or Lotus Notes files that I can then use in Hashcat? I know how to get them for Office documents using office2john.py but I'm stuck on the best methods for other files. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The method seem to be different for each hash. I suggest for you to open a question for each one.

Comment: Example for PDF Hash: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/82222/how-can-i-extract-the-hash-inside-a-encrypted-pdf-file

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question should be **specific** for:

- The **hash type** you are wanting to extract (PDF, Office, NT User, WPA... etc).
- The **program** that will process this hash (Cain&Abel, OCLHashCat, John the Ripper... etc).

So a specific question should be made for, at least, each hash.
[This](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/82222/how-can-i-extract-the-hash-inside-a-encrypted-pdf-file) is an example for PDF Hashes to bruteforce with OCLHashCat.