# How can I extract the hash inside an encrypted PDF file?

Tags: hash, pdf

As long as I know, the **encrypted PDF** files don't store the decryption password within them, but a hash asociated to this password.

When auditing security, a good attemp to break PDF files passwords is extracting this hash and bruteforcing it, for example using programs like [HashCat](http://hashcat.net/oclhashcat/).

What is the proper method to **extract the hash inside a PDF** file in order to auditing it with, say, HashCat?

Answers for **John the Ripper**  could be valid too, but I prefer HashCat format due to the easyness of making **GPU computing** work in Windows and bruteforce with **OCLHashCat** (the GPU version of HashCat). John the Ripper has a GPU version too, but JTR has no Windows version, at least with GPU enhancement.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

UPDATE 21 Dec 2017

The script pdf2john.py doesn't exist anymore. It has been substituted by a perl version, [pdf2john.pl](https://github.com/magnumripper/JohnTheRipper/blob/bleeding-jumbo/run/pdf2john.pl).

---

Extracted from [HashCat Forums](https://hashcat.net/forum/thread-4105-post-23368.html#pid23368), this method works for me (**requires Perl**):

--Download **pdf2john.pl** from the suite [John the Ripper](https://github.com/magnumripper/JohnTheRipper/) (**OCLHashCat** works with the **same hash format** as John the Ripper):

```
wget https://github.com/magnumripper/JohnTheRipper/archive/bleeding-jumbo.zip  
unzip bleeding-jumbo.zip
```

--Use it to **extract the hash** from your .pdf file:

```
perl JohnTheRipper-bleeding-jumbo/run/pdf2john.pl MyPDF.pdf > MyPDF-Hash.txt
```

--Output file `MyPDF-Hash.txt` must be **edited**. Original would be something like:

```
MyPDF.pdf:$pdf$4*4*128*1028*1*16*652fc762fdb12c47a5f90ddd2b99b809*32*dd86d858f914809078a4a47348d32c0fc4e9c08042a10e6434b48b698de7731f*32*3c1e693526d5bc8da15b99eea6cbc6ed2c2397e23e2c39d1974fdc004c588cff:::::MyPDF.pdf
```

so use your preferred editor:

```
nano MyPDF-Hash.txt
notepad MyPDF-Hash.txt
```

and leave only the **part inside double colons** `:` :

```
$pdf$4*4*128*1028*1*16*652fc762fdb12c47a5f90ddd2b99b809*32*dd86d858f914809078a4a47348d32c0fc4e9c08042a10e6434b48b698de7731f*32*3c1e693526d5bc8da15b99eea6cbc6ed2c2397e23e2c39d1974fdc004c588cff
```

--**Hint**: you can do the extraction and the edition in **one step** by using `sed` (UnxUtils version too, if you are doing it from Windows):

```
perl JohnTheRipper-bleeding-jumbo/run/pdf2john.pl MyPDF.pdf | sed "s/::.*$//" | sed "s/^.*://" > MyPDF-Hash.txt
```

--Your `MyPDF-Hash.txt` file is now **ready to use** with OCLHashCat (or John the Ripper).

NOTES:

- Tested working on CygWin (Windows).
- Tested working on Kali and Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: pdf2john.py doesn't exist anymore. It has been substituted by a [perl version](https://github.com/magnumripper/JohnTheRipper/blob/bleeding-jumbo/run/pdf2john.pl)

Comment: Copying the perl file out of the directory does not work. It needs to be where it is, in the "run" directory, otherwise you'll get an error.

Comment: Hey, this answer doesn't work, first because you have the file extension py and the file is a perl script.

Comment: To get rid of the irrelevante text on the hash, use this perl JohnTheRipper-bleeding-jumbo/run/pdf2john.pl MyPDF.pdf | awk -F":" '{ print $2}' > MyPDF-Hash.txt

Comment: I suggest an edit to this answer: don't download pdf2john.pl from the repository, just download the whole repository and run pdf2john.pl from within it.

Comment: I must say, this is the first time I've ever seen an application move *from* python *to* perl. I wonder... *why?*

Comment: FYI there is a site that runs that script for you if you don't mind uploading the pdf.
https://www.onlinehashcrack.com/tools-pdf-hash-extractor.php

Comment: I've just tried with the latest John the Ripper Jumbo (taken from Git, commit made on 2023-07-17) and there's no need to edit the hash file to leave only the part inside double colons, it worked just fine without changing anything. I suppose at some point they simplified this.